# Is it possible to use boost::foreach with std::map?

Tags: c++, boost, foreach

I find [boost::foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/foreach.html) very useful as it saves me a lot of writing. For example, let's say I want to print all the elements in a list:

```
std::list<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (std::list<int>::iterator i = numbers.begin(); i != numbers.end(); ++i)
   cout << *i << " ";
```

boost::foreach makes the code above much simplier:

```
std::list<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
BOOST_FOREACH (int i, numbers)
   cout << i << " ";
```

Much better! However I never figured out a way (if it's at all possible) to use it for `std::map`s. The documentation only has examples with types such as `vector` or `string`.

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate, but see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461507/how-to-use-boostforeach-with-a-boostptrmap/461908#461908

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to use:

```
typedef std::map<int, int> map_type;
map_type map = /* ... */;

BOOST_FOREACH(const map_type::value_type& myPair, map)
{
    // ...
}
```

The reason being that the macro expects two parameters. When you try to inline the pair definition, you introduce a second comma, making the macro three parameters instead. The preprocessor doesn't respect any C++ constructs, it only knows text.

So when you say `BOOST_FOREACH(pair<int, int>, map)`, the preprocessor sees these three arguments for the macro:

1.`pair<int`
 2. `int>`
 3. `map`

Which is wrong. This is [mentioned](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/foreach/pitfalls.html#) in the for-each documentation.

Comment: Make that `pair<const int, int>`.

Comment: The last edit introduces some misinformation. There is no undefined behavior, since the last two examples won't compile. `std::map` protects its key itself: if you have `map<Key, Value>` then the value type is `pair<const Key, Value>`. Note that it makes the key type const.

Comment: Can you edit your answer again? I accidentally rescinded my upvote and now it won't make me recast it unless you edit =p EDIT: oh, cool, I edited it myself and it worked :) +1 regiven!

Comment: Note in C++11 you can also just do `BOOST_FOREACH(const auto& myPair, map)`

Answer (score 20):

I use [Boost's Range Ex library](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/range_ex/doc/html/index.html) which implements some fancy range adaptors for iterating over map keys or values. For instance:

```
map<int, string> foo;
foo[3] = "three";
foo[7] = "seven";

BOOST_FOREACH(i, foo | map_keys)
   cout << i << "\n";


BOOST_FOREACH(str, foo | map_values)
   cout << str << "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can.  The trick is, however, that a map iterator points to a pair of the key and value.  It would look something like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> MapType;
MapType myMap;

// ... fill the map...

BOOST_FOREACH(MapType::value_type val, myMap)
{
    std::cout << val.first << ": " << val.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried with `BOOST_FOREACH(int i, map)`, `BOOST_FOREACH(pair<int, int>, map)`, etc. Can you post a working example?

Comment: Someone could mention that `BOOST_FOREACH` is a *macro*, and therefore it can't properly deal with the comma in the pair template. This is the reason why everybody is suggesting a typedef.

Comment: @UncleBens: I think the typedef just makes it look a whole lot cleaner, even if the macro can handle the comma (not sure whether it can).

Comment: Comma has only one meaning for the preprocessor - argument separator. It is not aware of templates and that a comma that falls between `<>` does not introduce another argument.

Comment: @UncleBens: Yes, it looks like you're right.  But that wasn't my thought in using the typedef.  I think that was the OP's problem all along, although I had no way to know that when I came up with the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but it's not really the best way to do things (as I've mentioned a few times before, for_each almost never is, and BOOST_FOREACH is only marginally better). For your first example, I think you'd be better off with:

```
std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

It works pretty similarly with a map, except that you have to define operator<< for it, since there isn't one already defined:

```
typedef map<std::string, int>::value_type vt;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, vt &v) { 
    return os << v.first << ": " << v.second;
}
```

...and once again, `std::copy` does the job quite nicely:

```
std::copy(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<vt>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: +1.  I agree with you, Jerry, although some might argue that having to define the operator (oops, you have a typo there!) is more trouble than the BOOST_FOREACH.

Comment: @Fred: They can argue that, and to an extremely minimal extent, it's even true. Then again, doing the job right often is a bit more work (at least up-front) than just hacking out something that sort of works.

Answer (score 2):

Typedefing a map pair is confusing. The most simplest way to iterate a map is with a tuple(just like in python):

```
std::map<int, int> mymap;
int key, value;
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::tie(key, value), mymap)
{
    ...
}
```

And don't worry, those commas won't confuse the preprocessor because I placed parenthesis around them.

Comment: This has a drawback of copying the value of the map. It might be expensive if it is not a primitive.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like the idea to be forced to add typedefs each time I wanted to use a foreach on a map. So here is my implementation based on the boost foreach code:

```
#ifndef MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP 

#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#define MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(x)  BOOST_PP_CAT(x, __LINE__)

namespace munzekonza {
namespace foreach_in_map_private {
inline bool set_false(bool& b) {
  b = false;
  return false;
}

}
}

#define MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP(key, value, map)                            \
for(auto MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_it) = map.begin();      \
        MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_it) != map.end();)       \
for(bool MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue) = true;       \
      MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue) &&               \
      MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_it) != map.end();          \
      (MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue)) ?              \
        ((void)++MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_it)) :          \
        (void)0)                                                              \
  if( munzekonza::foreach_in_map_private::set_false(                          \
          MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue))) {} else    \
  for( key = MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_it)->first;         \
        !MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue);              \
        MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue) = true)        \
  if( munzekonza::foreach_in_map_private::set_false(                          \
          MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue))) {} else    \
  for( value = MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_it)->second;      \
        !MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue);              \
        MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP_ID(_foreach_in_map_continue) = true)
```

Then you can use it in your code:
    #define foreach_in_map MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP

```
std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
mymap[0] = "oi";
mymap[1] = "noi";

std::map<int, std::string> newmap;

foreach_in_map(int key, const std::string& value, mymap) {
  newmap[key] = value;
}

ASSERT_EQ( newmap.size(), 2 );
ASSERT_EQ( newmap.count(0), 1 );
ASSERT_EQ( newmap.count(1), 1 );
ASSERT_EQ( newmap.at(0), "oi" );
ASSERT_EQ( newmap.at(1), "noi" );
```

You can also change the values:
    #define foreach_in_map MUNZEKONZA_FOREACH_IN_MAP

```
std::map<int, std::string> mymap;

mymap[0] = "oi";
mymap[1] = "noi";

std::map<int, std::string> newmap;

foreach_in_map(int key, std::string& value, mymap) {
  value = "voronoi" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(key);
}

ASSERT_EQ( mymap.size(), 2 );
ASSERT_EQ( mymap.count(0), 1 );
ASSERT_EQ( mymap.count(1), 1 );
ASSERT_EQ( mymap.at(0), "voronoi0" );
ASSERT_EQ( mymap.at(1), "voronoi1" );
```

Comment: if you don't like typedefs, just use #define !?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
typedef std::map<std::string,int>    MyMap;

MyMap    myMap;

BOOST_FOREACH(MyMap::value_type loop, myMap)
{ 
       // Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++0x you can more easily do:

```
map<int, string> entries;
/* Fill entries */

foreach(auto i, entries)
   cout << boost::format("%d = %s\n") % i.first % i.second;
```

Comment: Accoding to wikipedia the foreach syntax looks more like the java foreach `for(int& x : my_array) { x *= 2; }`

Comment: I believe the poster assumed the old practice of `#include<boost/foreach.hpp` and `#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH`