# boost for each problem

Tags: c++, boost, boost-foreach

```
std::map< std::string , std::string > matrix_int;
typedef std::pair< std::string , std::string > lp_type;
BOOST_FOREACH( lp_type &row, matrix_int ){

}
```

this can not be complied:
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'lp_type &'

when I have ',' in element type, boost doc says I can use typedef or predefine a var;
but what should I do when I want to get a reference?

Comment: Are you going to modify `row`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your typedef is incorrect; it needs to be:

```
typedef std::pair< const std::string , std::string > lp_type;
                   ^ note the added const
```

The key element in the map pair is const-qualified.

It would be a bit cleaner to use the `value_type` typedef; this way you don't repeat the type information:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> map_t;
map_t matrix_int;
BOOST_FOREACH(map_t::value_type& row, matrix_int){

}
```

Comment: Although technically correct, I would argue that using the inner typedef `value_type` of the map would be better, as it does not expose this intricacy.

Comment: @Matthieu:  Yeah; three people said that while I was editing to add that as a suggestion.  :-P  I agree wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 2):

See [Is it possible to use boost::foreach with std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104208/is-it-possible-to-use-boostforeach-with-stdmap).

Looks like you need to do:

```
typedef std::map< std::string, std::string > MyMap;
BOOST_FOREACH( MyMap::value_type& row, matrix_int ) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think James McNellis is right.  I'll add the suggestion that you take advantage of the `value_type` typedef that std::map provides.  Then your code could look like this:

```
typedef std::map< std::string , std::string > MyMap;
MyMap matrix_int;

BOOST_FOREACH( MyMap::value_type &row, matrix_int ){

}
```