# Boost C++ macro argument count error

Tags: c++, boost, macros, foreach, boost-foreach

In the following piece of code:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(std::pair<PID, bool> &itval, completedEs_) {
    allCompleted &= it->second;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> error: macro "BOOST_FOREACH" passed 3
>   arguments, but takes just 2

I'm only passing 2 arguments, what's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716865/c-boost-any-gotchas-with-boost-foreach/716872#716872

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104208/is-it-possible-to-use-boostforeach-with-stdmap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first type is being parsed as two arguments since it contains a comma.
As a workaround you could typedef the type:

```
typedef std::pair<PID, bool> PID_bool_pair;
BOOST_FOREACH( PID_bool_pair &itval, completedEs_) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because of BOOST_FOREACH macro limitations, rewrite it like:

```
//...
typedef std::pair<PID, bool> mypair;
BOOST_FOREACH(mypair &itval, completedEs_) {
    allCompleted &= it->second;
}
//...
```