# why BOOST_FOREACH cannot handle const boost::ptr_map?

Tags: c++, boost, foreach

```
void main()
{
  typedef boost::ptr_map<int, char>  MyMap;
  //typedef std::map<int, char *>  MyMap;  // in contrast with std type it works

  MyMap mymap;

  mymap[1] = new char('a');
  mymap[2] = new char('b');
  mymap[3] = new char('c');

  BOOST_FOREACH(MyMap::value_type value, mymap)
  {
    std::cout << value.first << "  " << value.second << std::endl;
  }

  MyMap const & const_mymap = mymap;

  BOOST_FOREACH(const MyMap::value_type value, const_mymap)
  {
    std::cout << value.first << "  " << value.second << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The following error message comes from GCC at the second BOOST_FOREACH

```
error: conversion from 'boost::ptr_container_detail::ref_pair<int, const char* const>' to non-scalar type 'boost::ptr_container_detail::ref_pair<int, char* const>' requested
```

I reckon that this is the weakness of the pointer container's ref_pair...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461507/how-to-use-boost-foreach-with-a-boostptr-map/2018410#2018410), it looks like you're right.  But there's a workaround.  Change your second loop to this:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(MyMap::const_iterator::value_type value, const_mymap)
{
    std::cout << value.first << "  " << value.second << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typedefing is also confusing when using maps. Its much simpler(and much more readable) to use a tuple instead. Here's how you can use a tuple:

```
int key;
char* value;
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::tie(key, value), mymap)
{
  std::cout << key << "  " << value << std::endl;
}
```

Plus, you can give more meaningful names instead of `value.first` and `value.second`.

Comment: I liked this until I went to look at the library to find out more... `"Tiers are tuples, where all elements are of non-const reference types."` Question is specifically about `const` references.

Comment: It will still work with const maps. The non-const reference is bound to the local variables not to the elements of the map.

Comment: will look at it again. Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't compile. I get the following error message. I have tried with the exact same code shared in the question along with this answer. Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Error message: `error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'boost::tuples::detail::tie_mapper<int, char*, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void>::type {aka boost::tuples::tuple<int&, char*&, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>}'` (contd...)

Comment: `and 'boost::iterators::iterator_reference<boost::ptr_map_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const int, void*> >, int, const char* const> >::type {aka boost::ptr_container_detail::ref_pair<int, const char* const>}')`