# Why doesn't ::boost::tie work with BOOST_FOREACH?

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, c++03

I want to use `BOOST_FOREACH` to iterate over a `boost::ptr_map`, and came across [this neat-looking solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8981254/252576). I would prefer using this for better readability, as against the other solutions given. I wrote the following code:

```
boost::ptr_map<int, std::string> int2strMap;
int x = 1;
int2strMap.insert(x, new std::string("one"));
int one;
std::string* two;
BOOST_FOREACH(::boost::tie(one, two), int2strMap)
{
   std::cout << one << two << std::endl;
}
```

However, this fails to compile, and gives me the below error (The full error message has several more lines, let me know if I should paste them.):

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'boost::tuples::detail::tie_mapper<int, std::basic_string<char>*, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void>::type {aka boost::tuples::tuple<int&, std::basic_string<char>*&, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>}' and 'boost::iterators::iterator_reference<boost::ptr_map_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, void*> >, int, std::basic_string<char>* const> >::type {aka boost::ptr_container_detail::ref_pair<int, std::basic_string<char>* const>}')
BOOST_FOREACH(::boost::tie(one, two), int2strMap)
```

It appears that the suggested solution works for a handful of people, and I am unable to figure out why it doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong here?

(Note: I am working on a prehistoric project, so stuck with using C++03. g++ version: 4.8.4)

Comment: Without checking the guts can't say for sure but it is probably the same reason you can't do this with a `std::tuple`.  It is only iterable using compile time constructs.

Comment: I have my doubts that the neat-looking solution ever worked, since it expects the iterator to give us a `std::pair`, but we only get something that [kinda looks like it](https://github.com/boostorg/ptr_container/blob/develop/include/boost/ptr_container/detail/map_iterator.hpp#L34). (And it doesn't look like the code changed since that answer was posted)

Comment: However, you can implement you own simple `tie` equivalent -- something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e01dca4a777269d0).

Comment: @Dan That is certainly a possibility, but I had hoped that 7 people wouldn't have upvoted it without checking if it is correct. Hmm...

Comment: @MaskedMan After some more digging through the boost report, I'm quite confident it never could have worked. As to what you say, it's sad, but having seen plenty of upvotes on utter garbage and countless examples of all levels of laziness, I tend to take the votes with a grain of salt -- especially when the answer doesn't have any references, working (and ideally live) sample, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question really should be "Why doesn't `boost::tie` work with `boost::ptr_map` (or rather the result of dereferencing its iterator)?" -- `BOOST_FOREACH` is quite innocent in all this.

### Investigation

If we look at the [version history of Boost](http://www.boost.org/users/history/), we can see that *Tuple* appears in version 1.24.0 and *Pointer Container* in version 1.33.0.

#### Tuple

Relevant tuple related code in github:

- recent release: https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp
- first release: https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.24.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp

Studying the code, we can make the following observations:

- `tie` has always created a `tuple`
  [[1]](https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.24.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp#L637)
  [[2]](https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp#L867)
- `tuple` has always derived from template `cons`
  [[1]](https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.24.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp#L362)
  [[2]](https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp#L474)
- `tuple` (and `cons`) always had assignment operators taking either a `cons` (i.e. another `tuple`)
  [[1]](https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.24.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp#L401)
  [[2]](https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp#L579)
  or a `std::pair`
  [[1]](https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.24.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp#L407)
  [[2]](https://github.com/boostorg/tuple/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp#L585)
  -- nothing else.

#### Pointer Container

Relevant pointer container related code in github:

- recent release: https://github.com/boostorg/ptr_container/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/ptr_container/detail/map_iterator.hpp
- third release: https://github.com/boostorg/ptr_container/blob/boost-1.34.0/include/boost/ptr_container/detail/map_iterator.hpp
- first release: https://github.com/boostorg/ptr_container/blob/boost-1.33.0/include/boost/ptr_container/detail/map_iterator.hpp

Studying the code, we can make the following observations:

- In first two releases (1.33.x), dereferencing the iterator gave us a reference to the value [[1]](https://github.com/boostorg/ptr_container/blob/boost-1.33.0/include/boost/ptr_container/detail/map_iterator.hpp#L54) [[2]](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html#upgrading-from-boost-v-1-33)
- Since the third release (1.34.0), we get a `ref_pair`, which somewhat looks like a `std::pair`, but really isn't
  [[1]](https://github.com/boostorg/ptr_container/blob/boost-1.34.0/include/boost/ptr_container/detail/map_iterator.hpp#L28)
  [[2]](https://github.com/boostorg/ptr_container/blob/boost-1.64.0/include/boost/ptr_container/detail/map_iterator.hpp#L34)
  [[3]](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html#upgrading-from-boost-v-1-33)

#### Conclusion

We can eliminate `BOOST_FOREACH` by just doing one iteration, and still get the same error:

```
boost::tie(one, two) = *int2strMap.begin();
```

Based on what we learned earlier, we know this is equivalent to

```
boost::tuple<int&, std::string*&>(one, two) = *int2strMap.begin();
```

We also know that `*int2strMap.begin()` will result in either  a `std::string` reference, or a `ref_pair`.

Since tuple has no assignment operator that would take either of those, the proposed snippet can not compile with any existing version of Boost.

---

### Workaround

Taking inspiration from the implementation of `boost::tuple` and `boost::tie`, we can write a simple `reference_pair` template that holds two references and allows assignment of anything that looks like a `pair` (i.e. has members `first` and `second`), along with a helper `tie` function that will create an instance of `reference_pair`.

#### Sample Code

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace {

template<class T0, class T1>
struct reference_pair
{
    T0& first;
    T1& second;

    reference_pair(T0& t0, T1& t1) : first(t0), second(t1) {}

    template<class U>
    reference_pair& operator=(const U& src) {
        first = src.first;
        second = src.second;
        return *this;
    }
};

template<class T0, class T1>
inline reference_pair<T0, T1> tie(T0& t0, T1& t1)
{
    return reference_pair<T0, T1>(t0, t1);
}

}

int main()
{
    boost::ptr_map<int, std::string> int2strMap;
    int n(0);
    int2strMap.insert(n, new std::string("one"));
    int2strMap.insert(++n, new std::string("two"));
    int2strMap.insert(++n, new std::string("three"));

    int one;
    std::string* two;

    BOOST_FOREACH(tie(one, two), int2strMap)
    {
       std::cout << one << " " << *two << std::endl;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb44b76ab178d643)</kbd>

#### Console Output

```
0 one
1 two
2 three
```